pythonanywhere: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'spam_detector_model2.joblib'
I am trying to run this application using pythonanywere.com but I getting this file not found error even when the file is present in the director:
2024-06-19 08:38:54,491: Error running WSGI application
2024-06-19 08:38:54,492: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'spam_detector_model2.joblib'
2024-06-19 08:38:54,492:   File "/var/www/spamdetector_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2024-06-19 08:38:54,492:     from spamdetector import app as application  # noqa
2024-06-19 08:38:54,492: 
2024-06-19 08:38:54,492:   File "/home/spamdetector/spam_detector/spamdetector.py", line 8, in <module>
2024-06-19 08:38:54,492:     model = joblib.load('spam_detector_model2.joblib')
2024-06-19 08:38:54,492: 
2024-06-19 08:38:54,492:   File "/home/spamdetector/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 650, in load
2024-06-19 08:38:54,493:     with open(filename, 'rb') as f:

below is my code:
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, redirect
import joblib
import logging
import smtplib

# Initialize Flask app and load the model
app = Flask(__name__)
model = joblib.load('spam_detector_model2.joblib')


@app.route('/send_feedback', methods=['POST'])
def send_feedback():
    name = request.form.get('name')
    email = request.form.get('email')
    message = request.form.get('message')

    # Email message setup
    email_message = f"Subject: Feedback from {name}\n\nFrom: {email}\n\nMessage: {message}"

    # Sending the email
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
        server.sendmail(EMAIL_HOST_USER, RECIPIENT_ADDRESS, email_message)
        server.close()
        return 'Feedback sent successfully!'
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('base.html')

@app.route('/feedback')
def feedback():
    return render_template('feedback_form.html')


@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    try:
        # Input validation
        email_text = request.form.get('text', '')
        if not email_text:
            app.logger.warning('No email text provided')
            return jsonify({'error': 'No email text provided'}), 400

        # Model prediction
        prediction = model.predict([email_text])
        app.logger.info('Prediction made for an email')
        return jsonify({'spam': bool(prediction[0])})

    except Exception as e:
        # Error handling
        app.logger.error(f"Error during prediction: {str(e)}")
        return jsonify({'error': 'Error occurred during prediction'}), 500

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    # Custom error handler for 404 Not Found
    app.logger.warning('Page not found')
    return jsonify({'error': 'Not Found'}), 404

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(e):
    # Custom error handler for 500 Internal Server Error
    app.logger.error('Internal server error')
    return jsonify({'error': 'Internal Server Error'}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)


The image attached shows the file is present in the directory
The file directory
please help
joblib and other modules and packages are install but the error keep coming

joblib.load('spam_detector_model2.joblib') either the file is not there  or working directory is not the same where that file is.   In that case, you either need to use absolute path to that joblib file or construct a relative path to a current working directory.

Thank you @rasjani. It works with changing it absolute path https://spamdetector.pythonanywhere.com/
